# Multiline Header and Custom First Page Header

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am tasked with arranging the LaTeX files for a journal. Right now, here is the LaTeX code (not mine, so I don't really know how to work around this). The first page of every paper has a "special header" and the rest has the normal fancy header.

As I understand it, the current "special header" is part of the body of the document. I would like to ask if there is some way to make the "special header" really part of the header environment. How do I go about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[LO]{\textsc{Title of Paper}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\textsc{Authors}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.75pt}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\maketitle
%\setcounter{page}{1}

\vspace{-1.7in}
\hrule
\vspace{0.02in}
{\sf \noindent{\small JOURNAL NAME \hfill OTHER STUFF}\\
\vspace{-.2in}\\
\noindent{\small  ISSN \ 0115-xxxx\hfill Vol. xx  No. x (xxx) pp.
1-13}}

\vspace{0.01in}
\hrule

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, if this is what you want, but you could define a special header in the preample, by simply using `\fancypagestyle{somename}` and then set `\thispagestyle{somename}` where you want the pagestyle to be different.

Answer (score 4):

As `\maketitle` sets the page style to `plain`, the best plain is to redefine the `plain` page style to include the header:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[LO]{\textsc{Title of Paper}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\textsc{Authors}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.75pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhead{%
    \vspace{-1.7in}
    \hrule
    \vspace{0.02in}
    \small
    \sffamily
    \noindent
    \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}
      JOURNAL NAME \hfill OTHER STUFF\\
      ISSN \ 0115-xxxx\hfill Vol. xx  No. x (xxx) pp. 1-13
    \end{tabular}
    \vspace{0.01in}
    \hrule
  }
}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\maketitle

Some text
\clearpage
Some more text


\end{document}
```